# Selenium Webdrive Chrome - Sometimes it hangs

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I come with a problem regarding Selenium I'm using it in a python application.
I created a simple code that opens the **--headless** browser, selects the chrome profile, and gets the OAUTH2 code from the URL.

The code works fine, but sometimes it freezes completely and hangs on the landing page and won't download the code from the url.
I don't get any feedback other than errors about DEV USB etc.

I'm using Selenium 4.8.0

I tried using selenium stealth but it didn't help.
Before starting I call a subprocess which kills chrome.exe.
Once out of 4 launches, it freezes.

The entire function in the code below.

```
async def allegroCODE(status):
        status.update(status="[bold green]Zdobywanie kodu...",spinner="bouncingBall", spinner_style="yellow")
        authorization_redirect_url = CODE_URL + '?response_type=code&client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + \
                                    '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URL
        try:
            FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
            subprocess.call("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe",stdout=FNULL,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        except:
            pass
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
        options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\crepe\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
        options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        ser = Service(r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options, service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
        # stealth(driver,
        #         languages=["en-US", "en"],
        #         vendor="Google Inc.",
        #         platform="Win32",
        #         webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        #         renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        #         fix_hairline=True,
        #         )

        driver.get(authorization_redirect_url)
        code = driver.current_url
        driver.quit()
        code = code.split('=')
        code_ex = code[1]
        console.log(f"[bold green]✅ Udało się zdobyć kod: {code_ex}")
        authorization_code = code_ex
        return authorization_code
```

Pls ignore my Polish logs : )

P.S. I saw a similar problem already on the forum, but unfortunately nothing solved my problem.
Therefore, I am writing with a separate question.

**EDITED:**

Logs:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:1059/devtools/browser/0497f13c-2bc0-439d-8a8f-2d5c2a597cb7
[17848:12192:0214/231451.183:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [23:14:51.183] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Urz╣dzenie do│╣czone do komputera nie dzia│a. (0x1F)

[17848:12192:0214/231451.183:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [23:14:51.183] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
[17848:12192:0214/231451.185:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [23:14:51.184] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Urz╣dzenie do│╣czone do komputera nie dzia│a. (0x1F)
```

Comment: include the exception thrown... or full list of the errors you are seeing.  If you never see an exception try/catch the driver.get() call.  (eventually it should throw something...)

Comment: @pcalkins The only information I receive, I saved in the edit of the post.

Comment: ok... nothing there that would shed light on this...  try/catch that driver.get() call and post any exceptions you find in the catch.  This could be a command timeout....(separate from page load timeout...)    OR, because of the nature of this link it's throwing off Selenium's wait for a page load.  (it'll check ready state methinks)  You may just want to add a sleep after using that driver.get()... but try/catch and see if it throws timeout when the freeze happens, or not.  Seems like the freeze might happen when it doesn't throw.  (timing issue with redirect/checking readystate/handle)

Comment: so when the timing is just right, the driver may get detached from the window handle... (just a wild guess really)  I don't think it expects the URL to be something that immediately redirects.

Comment: I gave up, I'll just put it in a loop that responds to no feedback.
Maybe there is a hidden problem somewhere deeper. Thank you for your willingness to help :)

I'll leave the topic open, maybe someone has encountered a similar problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who experienced a similar problem.

I dropped the get() function and replaced it with execute_script().

That is, instead of going to the landing page using get(), it calls the JS code that takes me there without crashing.

**Note that this is just the way I handled the problem, I still don't know why get() freezes so often.**

```
#my webdrive settings
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\**USER_NAME**\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
            ser = Service(r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

try:
  #run chrome
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)
  driver.set_window_size(800, 600)
  driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
  
  try:
    #execute js script 
    #This code takes me to the landing page. Then I check if I arrived 
    #by comparing the domain name **END_URL**, e.g. https://facebook.com/.
    driver.execute_script('''
    var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    var targetUrl = '**END_URL**';

    if (window.location.href.indexOf(targetUrl) === 0) {
        callback();
    } else {
    window.location.href = '**WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_GO**';
    }
    ''')
    #By using WebDriverWait, wait for the page to load the element. 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '**ELEMENT_ID**')))
  except Exception as err:
    print(err)
  finally:
    #Do what you want with the data, I collect the information from the url.
    code = driver.current_url
    #close driver
    driver.quit()

except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```